# ¿Cómo seleccionar y deseleccionar todos los checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Cómo puedo seleccionar y deseleccionar de manera correcta todas las filas de la tabla con los switches que están de color verde, ya que al momento de deseleccionar el checkbox que selecciona a todos NO ME PERMITE quitarle el check.

Estoy usando este script para seleccionar y deseleccionar los switches en verde, no sé qué error pueda ocurrir:

```
$(".chk-all-seleccion").on("change", function () {
        if ($(this).prop("checked", true)) {
            $(".chk-asistencia").each(function (index, element) {
                $(element).prop("checked", true);
                if ($(element).is(':checked')) {
                    $(element).parent().parent().css("background", "#FFE0B2");
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            $(".chk-asistencia").each(function (index, element) {
                $(element).prop("checked", true);
                $(element).parent().parent().css("background", "");
            });
        } 
    });
```

```js
/*SELECCIONAR Y DESELECIONAR CADA CHECKBOX*/
        $(document).on('change', '.chk-seleccion', function () {

            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).parent().parent().css("background","#FFE0B2");
            }
            else {
                $(this).parent().parent().css("background", "");
            }
        });
        
        /*SELECCIONAR Y DESELECIONAR TODOS LOS CHECKBOXES*/
        $(".chk-all-seleccion").on("change", function () {
            if ($(this).prop("checked", true)) {
                $(".chk-asistencia").each(function (index, element) {
                    if ($(element).is(':checked')) {
                        $(element).parent().parent().css("background", "#FFE0B2");
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                $(".chk-asistencia").each(function (index, element) {
                    $(element).prop("checked", true);
                    $(element).parent().parent().css("background", "");
                });
            } 
        });
```

```css
/*SWITCH*/
    :root {
        --color-title: #C8553D;
        --color-off: #dc3545;
        --color-on: #28a745;
        --color-gray: #EDEDED;
        --color-hover: #fff;
        --transition-time: 0.4s;
        --scale-size: scale(1.1);
        --switch-width: 60px;
        --switch-height: 25px;
    }

    .switch {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: var(--switch-width);
        height: var(--switch-height);
        background: var(--color-off);
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
        outline: none;
        transition: var(--transition-time);
        cursor: pointer;
    }

        .switch:before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: calc(var(--switch-width)/2);
            height: var(--switch-height);
            transform: var(--scale-size);
            box-shadow: 0 2px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
            background: var(--color-gray);
            transition: var(--transition-time);
        }

        .switch:checked {
            background: var(--color-on);
        }

        .switch:hover:before {
            background: var(--color-hover);
            transition: var(--transition-time);
        }

        .switch:checked:before {
            left: 50%;
        }

    .switch--circle {
        border-radius: 50px;
    }

        .switch--circle:before {
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

    @@keyframes pulse-animation {
        100% {
            transform: scale(1.2);
        }
    }
    
    /*CONTENEDOR*/
    .container {
        max-width: 1300px;
    }

    /*TABLA*/
    label {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .th-asistencia {
        width: 20%;
    }

    .td-asistencia {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }

    .asistencia_Inter {
        display: none;
    }

    .td-seleccion {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<label>Seleccionar todos los presentes: </label> 
<input class="chk-all-seleccion" type="checkbox" />

<hr />

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody><tr class="tr-head-interesado">
        <th class=""></th>
        <th>
            DNI:
        </th>
        <th>
            Apellido Paterno:
        </th>
        <th>
            Apellido Materno:
        </th>
        <th>
            Nombres:
        </th>
        <th class="th-asistencia">
            Asistencia:
        </th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">78547532</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">SAHUINCO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">VARGAS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">ALIDA JOAQUINA</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76544435</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">YOVERA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">INFANTE</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">JUAN MARCOS</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76474540</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">PAREDES</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">MENDOZA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">JULIO RONAL</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76475090</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">RAMOS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">HUANCA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">CLINDIO</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">72766321</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">MARCELO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">ATOCHE</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">JADIRA JAZMIN</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">75454576</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">ACHA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">CASTILLO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">GIANNINA NICOLE</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">75943583</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">ARHUIS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">CANALES</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">NATHALY ANTHUANED</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">75435908</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">REYES</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">ANICETO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">GERSON CHRISTIAN</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">74547658</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">CALLE</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">CALLE</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">ELVIS MANUEL</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76565446</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">ZAPANA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">DIAZ</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">RAY CARLOS</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76543354</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">MANAYAY</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">SANCHEZ</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">FERNANDO ALONSO</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76475156</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">POMA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">VIDAL</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">GIAN FRANCO ALEXIS</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">74536546</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">ROJAS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">CONDORI</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">MICHAEL DANIEL</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">71324657</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">SAMANIEGO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">AQUINO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">VLADIMIR ILICH</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">45654663</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">ALIAGA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">GUZMAN</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">CARELIA</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">74567564</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">FLORENTINO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">VASQUEZ</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">RENE</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76446650</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">CARLOS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">CESPEDES</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">GLADIS EDITA</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">77676575</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">MARCOS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">HERRERA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">FATIMA CELESTE</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">75435354</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">HUINCHO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">TAIPE</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">ESTEFANI PATRICIA</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76545433</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">ESPEZA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">GOMEZ</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">LIZ MARLENY</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existen diferentes formas de validar que un input tipo check esté `checado`, lo puedes visualizar en [.prop()](https://api.jquery.com/prop/) utilice el método `.is(':checked');` ya que en el ejemplo de la página, al utilizar `.attr()` no cambia el `booleano` a `false` al entrar al `change`, sólo lo valida una vez, pero con `.prop()` e `is.()` si lo hace, además tienes un error, al ser falso debes de poner `.prop("checked", false);`.

```js
/*SELECCIONAR Y DESELECIONAR CADA CHECKBOX*/
        $(document).on('change', '.chk-seleccion', function () {

            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(this).parent().parent().css("background","#FFE0B2");
            }
            else {
                $(this).parent().parent().css("background", "");
            }
        });
        
        /*SELECCIONAR Y DESELECIONAR TODOS LOS CHECKBOXES*/
        $(".chk-all-seleccion").on("change", function () {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) { 
                $(".chk-asistencia").each(function (index, element) {
                    $(element).prop("checked", true);
                    if ($(element).is(':checked')) {
                        $(element).parent().parent().css("background", "#FFE0B2");
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                $(".chk-asistencia").each(function (index, element) {
                    $(element).prop("checked", false);
                    $(element).parent().parent().css("background", "");
                });
            } 
        });
```

```css
/*SWITCH*/
    :root {
        --color-title: #C8553D;
        --color-off: #dc3545;
        --color-on: #28a745;
        --color-gray: #EDEDED;
        --color-hover: #fff;
        --transition-time: 0.4s;
        --scale-size: scale(1.1);
        --switch-width: 60px;
        --switch-height: 25px;
    }

    .switch {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: var(--switch-width);
        height: var(--switch-height);
        background: var(--color-off);
        box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
        outline: none;
        transition: var(--transition-time);
        cursor: pointer;
    }

        .switch:before {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: calc(var(--switch-width)/2);
            height: var(--switch-height);
            transform: var(--scale-size);
            box-shadow: 0 2px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
            background: var(--color-gray);
            transition: var(--transition-time);
        }

        .switch:checked {
            background: var(--color-on);
        }

        .switch:hover:before {
            background: var(--color-hover);
            transition: var(--transition-time);
        }

        .switch:checked:before {
            left: 50%;
        }

    .switch--circle {
        border-radius: 50px;
    }

        .switch--circle:before {
            border-radius: 50%;
        }

    @@keyframes pulse-animation {
        100% {
            transform: scale(1.2);
        }
    }
    
    /*CONTENEDOR*/
    .container {
        max-width: 1300px;
    }

    /*TABLA*/
    label {
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }

    .th-asistencia {
        width: 20%;
    }

    .td-asistencia {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }

    .asistencia_Inter {
        display: none;
    }

    .td-seleccion {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        height: 50px;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<label>Seleccionar todos los presentes: </label> 
<input class="chk-all-seleccion" type="checkbox" />

<hr />

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tbody><tr class="tr-head-interesado">
        <th class=""></th>
        <th>
            DNI:
        </th>
        <th>
            Apellido Paterno:
        </th>
        <th>
            Apellido Materno:
        </th>
        <th>
            Nombres:
        </th>
        <th class="th-asistencia">
            Asistencia:
        </th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">78547532</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">SAHUINCO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">VARGAS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">ALIDA JOAQUINA</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76544435</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">YOVERA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">INFANTE</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">JUAN MARCOS</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76474540</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">PAREDES</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">MENDOZA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">JULIO RONAL</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76475090</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">RAMOS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">HUANCA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">CLINDIO</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">72766321</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">MARCELO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">ATOCHE</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">JADIRA JAZMIN</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">75454576</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">ACHA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">CASTILLO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">GIANNINA NICOLE</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">75943583</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">ARHUIS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">CANALES</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">NATHALY ANTHUANED</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">75435908</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">REYES</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">ANICETO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">GERSON CHRISTIAN</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">74547658</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">CALLE</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">CALLE</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">ELVIS MANUEL</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76565446</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">ZAPANA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">DIAZ</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">RAY CARLOS</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76543354</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">MANAYAY</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">SANCHEZ</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">FERNANDO ALONSO</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76475156</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">POMA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">VIDAL</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">GIAN FRANCO ALEXIS</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">74536546</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">ROJAS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">CONDORI</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">MICHAEL DANIEL</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">71324657</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">SAMANIEGO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">AQUINO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">VLADIMIR ILICH</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">45654663</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">ALIAGA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">GUZMAN</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">CARELIA</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">74567564</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">FLORENTINO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">VASQUEZ</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">RENE</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76446650</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">CARLOS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">CESPEDES</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">GLADIS EDITA</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">77676575</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">MARCOS</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">HERRERA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">FATIMA CELESTE</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">75435354</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">HUINCHO</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">TAIPE</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">ESTEFANI PATRICIA</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">ASISTIO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-interesado">
        <td class="td-seleccion">
            <input class="chk-seleccion" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="dni_Inter">76545433</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apePat_Inter">ESPEZA</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="apeMat_Inter">GOMEZ</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="nombres_Inter">LIZ MARLENY</label>
        </td>
        <td class="td-asistencia">
            <label>FALTO</label>
            <input class="chk-asistencia switch switch--circle" style="" type="checkbox">
            <label>ASISTIO</label>
            <label class="asistencia_Inter">FALTO</label>
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody></table>
```